# Unsing ng-selected on a dinamically generated <select>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select that is generated dynamically and I want one of the values to be selected by default. The value that is going to be selected depends on what record the user is editing.
I have the following code that isn't currently working:

```
<select ng-model="record.chain" name="chain" class="form-control" ng-change="updateBrands(record.chain)">
                        <option ng-selected="{{ x.name == 'record.nameChain '}}" ng-repeat="x in chains" value="{{x.type}} {{x.name}}">{{x.name}}</option>
```

The `ng-change`part is used to update another select.
Do you have an idea on how I can achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `'record.nameChain '` ... you want to compare to the value of that scope variable not to that string

Comment: @charlietfl that disn't work :(

Comment: OK...has been a long time since I used angularjs but some directives don't use `{{}}` Try `ng-selected ="x.name == record.nameChain"` without the `{{}}`. Also using `ng-options` is a more common approach on the `<select>` than using `ng-repeat` and `ng-selected` on the `<option>`. And  I don't think `ng-model` works with `ng-selected` either. Setting the ng-model value in controller should help there

Comment: No curly brackets required in ng-selected. Don’t use quotes Inside either around record.nameChain. Agree with others here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
<select ng-model="record.nameChain" ng-options="x.name as x.name for x in chains">
```

Thanks to the people who suggested using options.